# Debug a Webservice locally in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat

I've got a service which I'm trying to debug. I can debug the client-side of the service ie to the point the WS is called and results returned by the WS but not the service/server-side of that service.

I've had a look at several articles on this and have strictly followed instructions but I'm still not able to achieve the desired result. I'm running the WS on Tomcat an dusing Eclipse IDE. Can somebody help? The steps that I've followed

A) Setting tomcat in debug mode

set JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
catalina.bat jpda start 
I've added the following lines to the catalina.bat files located at {catalina_home}/bin directory.

B) Deploying your application to Tomcat 
I wasnt sure whether needed or not but I've had already added the war file in the webapps folder previously and hence have the corresponding folder

C) Connecting Eclipse to Tomcat for debugging 
Now this is where I'm not I'm not sure of the settings.

1) Start Eclipse 
2) open the project containing the service that you want to debug 
3) click on the arrow close to the debug button (the little bug) to see the drop down menu 
click on open debug dialog... (may also be labeled "Debug Configurations...") 
4) in the debug window double click on the Remote Java Application on the left hand side list. This will create a new debug profile.
5) choose a name for the debug profile 
6) select the project you want to debug 
(Which project should I be using?? I've selected the webservice project although its a different project that is used for starting the application and from there the webservice is called from)
7) the host is the address for your tomcat ie localhost
8) the port is the one you configured in when starting Tomcat, 8000 by default 
9) Click on debug

On doing that I get the error "Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused. Connection refused"

I have the source code for both service and client and have them as separate projects in my eclipse.

What needs to be done differently??

Comment: do you have a local webserver set up? or are you sending data remotely?

Comment: HI, please see the above edited post for more details. I'm just having data locally and have a tomcate setup locally..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't started Tomcat first with remote debugging options (A) and after that connect Eclipse via remote debugging (C).

But you do not necessarily have to use remote debugging. Another option is to launch your server-side (service) project from within Eclipse in debug mode:
Your project must be dynamic web project (Dynamic Web Module facet) and then on this project's context menu choose Debug As > Debug on Server (you can define here a server that it will use such as Tomcat).

Comment: Hi Padis, how do I make my project as Dynamic Web Project? If I right click on the project-->properties->Project Facets and check the Dynamic Web Module, I get an error message saying that Dynamic Web Module 2.4 requires Java 1.3 or newer.

Comment: But in my Runtimes tab I have Apache Tomcat v6.0 and jdk1.6.0_21. None of the options are checked though!! Which runtime should I select and why is it complaining about needeing Java1.3 or higher!! Please help!! Thanks

Comment: You can either create new dynamic project - from menu bar: File > New > Project... In the first step of wizard choose Web > Dynamic Web project. Then click Next. In the second step choose Target Runtime or add new runtime (your Tomcat).

Comment: For existing project in Project Facets you might need to tick also Java facet (Dynamic Web Project facet depends on this on). Then you should be able to apply the changes. More about dynamic web module can be found here: http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html

Comment: Padis,thats great help!! I'llhave a look and let you know if that worked. Thanks again..

Comment: I've made the changes in the project Facets and checked the 'Java' and 'Dynamic Web Module' facets. Also, have checked Tomcat option in the Targeted Runtimes. After that I've deployed that project y adding this project to Tomcat in the server view by right-click on Tomcat in eclipse server view -> Add and Remove. Once that web project is added to Tomcat from within Eclipse, a project is deployed under <Tomcat Installation>/webapps folder. I have now started the Tomcat server in Debug mode and on right-clicking on the project --> Debug As --> Debug on Server, but am getting an error

Comment: when invoking the service and says HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource is not available. Any suggestions??